# List of websites

Tags: php, url

Is there a way to get the url's of google results on big scale? So instead of 10 results 100 or 1000?

(example: http://goohackle.com/tools/google-parser/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On http://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en you can set "results per page" option.

Edit:

I think this code snippet should be self-explanatory

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=test&num=100";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$anchors = $xpath->query('//a[@class="l"]');
foreach($anchors as $anchor)
    echo $anchor->getAttribute('href').'<br/>';
```

Edit #2:

As @JasCav already said, you should use this at your own responsibility. It's against Google's ToS and they would probably detect it eventually.

Comment: I mean plain url's, not complete results

Comment: I updated my answer, you should be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 2):

From a technical perspective you can do it, but it is against Google's TOS to actually do it.

**Update**: To my knowledge, there is not any service that would allow you to do this because, ultimately, Google controls who has access to their services and data. As a result, they also control who (and how) individuals can use their data. Using a tool like the one you described would allow someone to circumvent parts of Google (AKA - advertisements) that Google definitely does not want bypassed as that is their revenue stream and their customers (AKA - advertisers) would move onto some other service if they knew their ads were being bypassed.

Comment: @Kevin - I updated my answer with an explanation of why you can't do what you want to do.